# How to include support documents in xcode cocoa app?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, bundle, macos-sierra

In iOS version of app, sample/template files are added to Xcode in a group and then become a directory of that name within the app bundle. Easy enough.

What is the Cocoa equivalent? When I try the same thing, Xcode (Swift 3) fails on build with a "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1". How does one add support files (or directory of files) to a Cocoa app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS, I guess you mean that, every App creates a Resources Folder inside the NSBundle. Just check with right click "Show Bundle Content".
If you add resources to Xcode, just by dragging the file anywhere in your project navigation, will be asked to copy that file if needed.

I usually create a group with Supporting File, but thats arbitrary, because it has nothing to do with the file structure inside the project folder on disk nor with the product package.
[image]

To create groups just right mouse and select group.
[image]

This copies the file inside the Xcode project Folder. And if you choose to add target, then the file will be included to that Resource folder.

You can ask for that File with:

```
 let bundle = Bundle.main
 let path = bundle.path(forResource: "Test", ofType: "txt")
```

## Edit

if you have to code sign your resources, then ope the copy files menu in Build Phases, add with the plus button your resource and check code sign on copy. This should provide a proper signing for your resource.
Hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the images and explanation. I have been doing that in much the way described. To narrow the problem further, the failure to code sign is only if the file is one of my app's documents (included as a user template, for example). If I add a .txt file, all is fine, but adding a document for my app results in the stated error.

Comment: I provided you an edit on code signing. But with kind of are these documents, that they requests code signing? I wrote a app with template, and the work well without.

Comment: Wow. Copy Files wasn't listed as one of the Build Phases, and then the menu item to add Copy Files was disabled, so I never would have found it without your answer. So thank you! After clicking away from the project window and then clicking back to it, the Add Copy Files Build Phase menu item was enabled, and it worked as you described. I'm happy with how many things are the same for iOS and macOS, but it's extra confusing when something is different. Again, thank you.